# Fn.Transform without AWS::Include

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

You will find 1000 samples using:

```
Resources:
  XXXXAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      DefinitionBody:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location: !Sub s3://${BucketName}/openapi.yml
      StageName: !Sub ${StageName}
```

Transform calls a macro `AWS::Include`, which will load a file from s3, do template substitution and returns the file as object. I would like to exactly this - but with a local file. `AWS::Include` will only accept s3 references - any ideas?

Comment: Are you using CDK?

Answer (score 1):

Based on AWS documentation, it will support include files only from S3.
If keeping the files in S3 for long term is a problem, then it can expired automatically using S3 configuration.

Comment: Yeah the phases of synthesis and deployment became clear to me going through the documentation. Feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation executes on AWS servers and can't access your local files on your workstation. So no, you can't use local files in AWS::Include.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/assets.html

Assets were what I needed. I can define a local asset and it will be automatically deployed to the bucket used for the deployment. So no need to manually copy and secure files.